# Always return X number of rows

Tags: oracle, null, rows

We have a set of values which we use to populate a bar chart.  For this application, we will always need 5 years of data, we will always need 5 rows of data, even if the values are NULL.

See this query.  Assume that the DATE column goes from 2017, 2016, 2015.........even those we may have no data for 2014 & 2013, I will need to return a 2014 & 2013 for, with a NULL as the other column.....

```
SELECT period_date, actual_eps
  FROM (SELECT LAST_DAY(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(period_date),'YYYYMM')) period_date, actual_eps
        FROM period_data
        WHERE ticker = 'ADRO'
          AND period_type = 'A'
          AND actual_eps IS NOT NULL
        ORDER BY period_date DESC NULLS LAST)
  WHERE rownum <= 5;
```

So, it will return what rows it has, up to 5, and NULL for the other rows which it does not have, up to 5.......

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just to clarify, if in your examples you did have data for 2012 and 2011, would you want to see that - so 2017, 2016, 2015, 2012, 2011 - or just the first three then nulls? What if you have other gaps? In your example there is no data for 2018 or 2019, right?

Comment: Your question involves generating data for 5 years, but the query you show is on a month basis. Also, why do you have `TO_DATE(TO_CHAR())`? That looks very suspicious.

Comment: Not really month.  The type is A indicating ANNUAL.  And the YYYYMM is simply the companies reporting fiscal year.......

Comment: But basically I need 5 rows.  From the most recent, 5 years back.......that would be 5 record of type A.   And for any missing, just the date and NULL is all.........any easy way to do this?

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected output.

Comment: Not sure how to format properly on this windows;

Like this is all rows are there:
2017,45
2016,35
2015,55
2014,65
2013,10

And if rows were missing:
2017,45
2016,35
2015,55
2014,
2013,

Answer (score 1):

Try using a [Common Table Expression/Subquery Factoring](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/with-clause) to generate rows for each year value. Use a `RIGHT JOIN` to generate `NULL`s for any missing rows.
Normally I would use a `LEFT JOIN`. But in this case I think it reads better this way.
Use `NVL` to substitute the `year` for `NULL` `period_date` values.

```
with years as
(
    select to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY') as year from dual
    UNION ALL
    select to_char(add_months(sysdate,-12), 'YYYY') as year from dual
    UNION ALL
    select to_char(add_months(sysdate,-24), 'YYYY') as year from dual
    UNION ALL
    select to_char(add_months(sysdate,-36), 'YYYY') as year from dual
    UNION ALL
    select to_char(add_months(sysdate,-48), 'YYYY') as year from dual
)
SELECT
NVL(TO_CHAR(LAST_DAY(pd.period_date),'YYYYMM'),y.year) as period_date,
pd.actual_eps
FROM period_data pd
RIGHT JOIN years y ON y.year = to_char(pd.period_date,'YYYY')
                  AND pd.ticker = 'ADRO'
                  AND pd.period_type = 'A'
                  AND pd.actual_eps IS NOT NULL
WHERE rownum <= 5
ORDER BY period_date desc, actual_eps nulls last;
```

Output:

```
| PERIOD_DATE | ACTUAL_EPS |
|-------------|------------|
|      201902 |        foo |
|      201802 |        foo |
|      201702 |        foo |
|        2016 |     (null) |
|        2015 |     (null) |
```

[SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/04bab/1)